# Open plaintext files like python files

Tags: google-colaboratory

If you tinker a lot with Google Colab maybe you want to edit some .txt files or view a .csv file or any other kind of .csv files, you can already open python files.
If you go to the file directory listing and click

[image]

Just click on the file you want to open, and you open a new tab

[image]

However if this file is not a python file, you simply download it, is there a way to view the file in browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a library to show files easily in Colab.

```
!pip install kora
```

For any text file, you can use `bat` which provide syntax highlight. See [documentation](https://github.com/sharkdp/bat)

```
import kora.install.bat
!bat sample_data/README.md
```

For a csv, you can use google.colab.data_table, which I simplify calling it a bit.

```
import pandas as pd
import kora.data_table
pd.read_csv('sample_data/california_housing_test.csv')
```

For a json file, it can make a collapsible display

```
from kora.json import render
render('sample_data/anscombe.json')
```

See all 3 examples in [this notebook](https://colab.fan/1CKm-rIrBozBsdnQx4pwepn13ttPgdcyg).